# Formula Parse Error when using Join function

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to use the JOIN function to concatenate all the values of a column using a space and the at-sign (" @") as a delimiter. I'm receiving a Formula Parse Error when using the following text:

```
=JOIN(" @",!A2:A)
```

The referenced column is completely empty right now. Is that what's causing it not to function? If so, is there another way I can concatenate a row with a delimiter that will function even when some of the referenced cells are empty?

If it helps [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z10orIgv24zQhI_VXjEm6nwWY9PVlCJ7z4FslYaizoQ/edit?usp=sharing) is a link to the spreadsheet. The "Buyers Pinglist" is the one I need help with.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the formula in an IFERROR if you don't want the #N/A to show:

`= IFERROR(JOIN( " @" ," ", FILTER(B3:B, NOT(B3:B = "") )))`

The formula seems to work as soon as a value is added to the 'Buyers' tab - the issue is that when the column B is completely empty then there is no data returned by the FILTER and hence nothing for the formula to JOIN